# Instance variable doesn't load in actionmailer preview Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ActionMailer Preview is ignoring the instances of the objects that are being loaded into the view. I get nilclass even when an object exist. How do you load instance variables with actionmailer preview?

contract_mailer_preview.rb

## Preview all emails at

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/contract_mailer
class ContractMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  def modification_request_notification
    @process_owner = User.find(1)
    @provider_contract = Contract.find_by_hash_id("JEmZGSJnyyeerbya")

ContractMailer.modification_request_notification(@provider_contract,@process_owner)
  end
end
```

contract_mailer.rb

```
 def modification_request_notification(provider_contract, admin)
    @admin = admin
    @contract = provider_contract
    mail(to: @admin, subject: "Modification Request(s) Available for Contract")
  end
```

server log error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
    381:                           <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="flexibleContainer">
    382:                             <tr>
    383:                               <td align="left" valign="top" class="textContent">
```

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please include the full error message and the especially the line that raises the error. Have you ensured that is not a typo such as `admin.name` instead of `@admin.name`?

Comment: I used the instance variable, not the local variable in the mailer view. It's unable to find the object for some odd reason

Comment: Why not show us the actual code that proves it instead of just asking us to guess what misstake you made? Nil errors are programmer error 99% of the time and there is no way we can help you without having the complete picture.

Comment: I fixed it, there was a referencing issue with adding the instance variable to the preview method.

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable was not being referenced correctly. It had to be referenced in the normal method, but not in the preview method